# How do I set explorer.exe to run on Windows 10 boot?

Tags: windows-10

Recently I removed a mining malware from a Windows 10 computer that was redirecting the explorer.exe in registry. Now that I have removed the malware, explorer.exe won't run after login screen. I have to manually start explorer.exe in cmd.

I removed the malware following instructions from :
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9fb738ab-2f3d-4a07-ac8a-173d63a47f87/cmd-not-working-due-to-an-error-the-error-occurs-on-practically-everything?forum=win10itprogeneral

I have also tried running :

```
sfc /scannow"
```

But it didn't help.

The registry for Winlogon looks as it should:

Shell :  REG__SZ  :  explorer.exe

Any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

Okey, so i solved the issue.

I missed that there were a registry key called 'Shell' under current user(HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon ) also. I removed that and now it works fine.